# Array in state on update not replacing the array data instead appending the array again & again

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Want to store API data in state array variable. And this API will be called every 5 minutes to check for updates, so on every API call I will store the API array data in the state array variable and loop through the state array and display the data in table. kindly check my code and suggest me a solution? and Also I have another question what this statement will actually do [...this.state.info1, result.info1] it will append data to existing array or will replace the old array?

I put set Interval and called the API got the results and update the value in the state array so every time it should show one array of data(index 0) but its increasing the array index every time on update like (index 0, index 1)

```
this.state = {
  Info1 : [],
  Info2 : [],
  Info3 : []
}

componentDidMount() {
this.timer = setInterval(() => this.getSchedulerDashboard_Data(),100000);
this.getSchedulerDashboard_Data();
}

getSchedulerDashboard_Data () {
fetch('URL', {
  method : 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body :JSON.stringify({
    …..
  })
  …..
  ….
  ….
 .then(result => {
   this.setState({
      Info1 : [...this.state.Info1, result.info1],
      Info2 : [...this.state.Inf02, result.info2],
      Info3 : [...this.state.Info3, result.info3]
    }

  render() {
   ….
   ….
  console.log(
  this.state.Info1.map (data => {
     return (data)     //data will print the array 
     })
   })
  )


Actual results :
 on page load the array contains 11 records

[Array(11)]      //array contains one array of data at 0 index
 0: (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

//Data inside the array at index(0& 1)
0: {name: "john", age: "25", country: "England"}
1: {name: "joe", age: "45", country: "France", }

after the time interval, API is called again and state is update then the result is

(2) [Array(11), Array(11)]          //see the array increased with index(0&1) which I doesn't want
 0: (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 1: (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 length: 2
 __proto__: Array(0)

//Data inside the array at index(0& 1)
0: {name: "john", age: "25", country: "England"}
1: {name: "joe", age: "45", country: "France", }

//Data inside the array at index(0& 1)
0: {name: "john", age: "25", country: "England"} 
1: {name: "joe", age: "45", country: "France", }

Expected result should be:
on page load:

[Array(11)]      //array contains one array of data at 0 index
0: (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

//Data inside the array at index(0& 1)
0: {name: "john", age: "25", country: "England"}
1: {name: "joe", age: "45", country: "France", }

After time interval the result should be the same

[Array(11)]      //array contains one array of data at 0 index
0: (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
length: 1
 __proto__: Array(0)

//Data inside the array at index(0& 1)
0: {name: "john", age: "25", country: "England"}
1: {name: "joe", age: "45", country: "France", }
```

Comment: Your `result.info1`, `result.info2`, `result.info3` are array i guess, you need to spread them(if u want to append the existing array) or simply assign result to their respective state . Depending on your logic

Comment: if I assign result.info1 to state array then In console if we print the result will be  empty array   [ ] 
     length: 0
__proto__: Array(0) for console.log(this.state.Info1) that's y not saving directly to the array

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You are appending your data instead of updating with the new data.

change

```
Info1 : [...this.state.Info1, result.info1],
Info2 : [...this.state.Inf02, result.info2],
Info3 : [...this.state.Info3, result.info3]
```

to

```
this.setState({
  Info1 : result.info1,
  Info2 : result.info2,
  Info3 : result.info3
})
```

Comment: yes your right @Junius L. I tried it already but if you if iterate the Info1 array it will say the array is empty because we define Info1 in state as empty array, so that's y I took the previous state of array and stored result.info1 in it. you understand right?? please help me

Comment: this.setState({
  Info1 : result.info1
})  directly assigned and printed the result in console like (this.state.Info1) then I got  [ ] length: 0 proto: Array(0) . Because I defined the array as empty

Comment: do `this.setState({
  Info1 : result.info1,
  Info2 : result.info2,
  Info3 : result.info3
}, () => console.log(this.state.Info1) )`

Comment: looks like you are getting an array inside an array, try `this.setState({ Info1: [].concat.apply([], result.info1), ...})`

Comment: yes your right its array inside an array and I tried your solution will full hope but it shows empty [ ] same problem

Comment: Hi, I have fixed the mentioned issue after long research, First in state I have changed the array to  
this.state = {
  Info1 : {},
  Info2 : {},
  Info3 : {}
} 
……. fetch response
.then(result => {
   this.setState({
      Info1 : result.info1,
      Info2 : result.info2,
      Info3 : result.info3
    }
after setting the array in state, iterate and display the array in table like
Object.keys(this.state.Info1).map( (key,index) => {
return (
<tr key={index}></tr>
<td>{this.state.Info1[key].name</td>
})

Comment: Thank u all for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Fixed the issue by own, first changed the state variable

    this.state = {
       Info1 : {},
       Info2 : {},
       Info3 : {}
    } 
……. fetch response
    .then(result => {
       this.setState({
            Info1 : result.info1,
            Info2 : result.info2,
            Info3 : result.info3
        }

after setting the array in state, iterate and display the array in table like

      Object.keys(this.state.Info1).map( (key,index) => {
       return (
         <tr key={index}></tr>
         <td>{this.state.Info1[key].name</td>
          })

I used Object.keys to iterate because can't able to use map directly
```